# vtk autoinit linker error

Tags: c++, cmake, debian, vtk

I have a very confusing (at least for me :) ) problem with linking to vtk-libraries. On one desktop pc, my code compiles without any error. I have an identical installation on another pc, but there, I get linker errors.

On both pc's are installed: itk 4.8, vtk 6.3 and cmake 3.3. Both are debian-systems (8.1 - jessie).

[ 96%] Linking CXX executable project
CMakeFiles/project.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `vtkRenderingVolume_AutoInit::~vtkRenderingVolume_AutoInit()':
/usr/local/include/vtk-6.3/vtkRenderingVolumeModule.h:44: undefined reference to`vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL_AutoInit_Destruct()'
CMakeFiles/project.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL_ModuleInit::~vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL_ModuleInit()':
project/main.cpp:4: undefined reference to`vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL_AutoInit_Destruct()'
CMakeFiles/project.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL_ModuleInit':
project/main.cpp:4: undefined reference to`vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL_AutoInit_Construct()'
CMakeFiles/project.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `vtkRenderingVolume_AutoInit':
/usr/local/include/vtk-6.3/vtkRenderingVolumeModule.h:44: undefined reference to`vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL_AutoInit_Construct()'
libcommon.a(datareader.cpp.o): In function `vtkRenderingVolume_AutoInit':
/usr/local/include/vtk-6.3/vtkRenderingVolumeModule.h:44: undefined reference to`vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL_AutoInit_Construct()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/project.dir/build.make:326: recipe for target 'project' failed

I tried to fix those errors with adding

```
#include <vtkAutoInit.h>

VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingOpenGL);
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL);
```

to the file where I am using the vtk libraries, but it didn't help.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I am wondering, why it works on one of those pcs but not on the other one.

thank you very much!

Update: I fixed my problem by switching the position of

```
find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})
```

in the CMakeLists to the end. However, does anyone know, why it makes such a huge difference for different pcs?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the VTK_USE_FILE is found, your code should compile correctly. In your other PC, VTK_USE_FILE was already found from a previous configuration and sits in a CMake cache entry, so that is why it compiles fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using Nightly,
Your should put these in front of your including any vtk headers.

`#include <vtkAutoInit.h>`
`VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingOpenGL);`
`VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkInteractionStyle);`
`VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingFreeType);`
`VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL);`

and link all the library you made from vtk source